# Is there a concept of test suites in Gradle/Spock land?

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock

Groovy/Gradle project here that uses Spock for unit testing.

Does Spock and/or Gradle support test suites or named sets of tests? For reasons outside the scope of this question, there are certain Spock tests (`Specifications`) that the CI server just can't run.

So it would be great to divide all my app's Spock tests into two groups:

1. "`ci-tests`"; and
2. "`local-only-tests`"

And then perhaps we could invoke them via:

```
./gradlew test --suite ci-tests
```

etc. Is this possible? If so, what does the setup/config look like?

Comment: Spock is based on JUnit, so I would think you could use the standard approach to developing suites. For the Gradle integration take a look at the Gradle unit test plugin documentation for junit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate the tests that should not run in your CI server with the Spock annotation @IgnoreIf(  ).

See the documentation here: https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/extensions.html#_ignoreif

All you need to do is let the CI server set an environment variable, and exclude the test class if that variable is set.

Spock even have properties inside the closure to make it easy:

@IgnoreIf({ sys.isCiServer })

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a submodule `my-app-ci-test`, with the following in build.gradle:

```
test {
    enabled = false
}
task functionalTest(type: Test) {
}
```

Then you place your tests in `src/test/groovy` and run `./gradlew functionalTest`.

Alternatively, you could include them in the same module and configure the `test` and `functionalTest` tasks with `includes` / `excludes`

```
test {
    exclude '**/*FunctionalTest.groovy'
}
task functionalTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/*FunctionalTest.groovy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Junit test-runner for Spock tests, you may use `@Category` annotation. Example [by article](https://www.testwithspring.com/lesson/running-unit-tests-with-gradle-spock-edition/) and [official documentation](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html):

```
 public interface FastTests {
 }

 public interface SlowTests {
 }

 public interface SmokeTests
 }

 public static class A {
     @Test
     public void a() {
         fail();
     }

     @Category(SlowTests.class)
     @Test
     public void b() {
     }

     @Category({FastTests.class, SmokeTests.class})
     @Test
     public void c() {
     }
 }

 @Category({SlowTests.class, FastTests.class})
 public static class B {
     @Test
     public void d() {
     }
 }
```

```
test {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'package.FastTests'
    }
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Categories are no longer supported in JUnit 5, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66371811/1237617 for a workaround

Comment: @JakubBochenski, I think in Junit 5 it should be just replaced by `@Tag` annotation as by of the migration guide: https://www.arhohuttunen.com/junit-5-migration/#categories

Comment: if you want to take the time to edit/sed all your tests then sure, that's the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `SpockConfiguration.groovy` to allow passing include/exclude via system properties

```
    runner {
        exclude {
            System.properties['spock.exclude.annotations']
                ?.split(',')
                *.trim()
                ?.each {
                    try {
                        annotation Class.forName(it)
                        println "Excluding ${it}"
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        println "Can't load ${it}: ${e.message}"
                    }
                }
        }
        include {
            System.properties['spock.include.annotations']
                ?.split(',')
                *.trim()
                ?.each {
                    try {
                        annotation Class.forName(it)
                        println "Including ${it}"
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        println "Can't load ${it}: ${e.message}"
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```